# spring boot native query result set psudo column not seen

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-native-query

**Consider below code that pull data set form table called "ice" form mysqlDB . problem is I can see IceCreamModel{id=101, description='vanilla', price=10, mulfactor=2} . but could not view "total" psudo" column when code get excuted.**

```
public interface IceCreamRepository extends jpaRepository<IceCreamModel,Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT id, description,price, mulfactor, price * mulfactor as 'total' FROM ice WHERE id=101",nativeQuery = true)
    List<IceCreamModel> getMul();
}

    @Autowired
    private IceCreamRepository iceCreamRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DesignPatternsApplication.class, args); 
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        getMul();
    }


    private void getMul() {
        List<IceCreamModel> list=iceCreamRepository.getMul();
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

@Entity

public class IceCreamModel implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private  String description;
private int price;
private int mulfactor;
```

}

//
[Mysql Query result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83SB8.png)

[repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD2bw.png)

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6MWi.png)

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: Does IceCreamModel have total field?

Comment: no(IceCreamModel.class), SELECT id, description,price, mulfactor, (price * mulfactor) as 'total' FROM ice WHERE id=101, this is the query .pseudo columns in mysql

Comment: does your query execute without total? Field like id, description,price, mulfactor are defined in model and it automatically bind from query to model where total column is not in model so it's not bind.

Comment: One thing i am sugesting is multiply price and  mulfactor where it need instead of query.

Comment: If I ran on toad for mysql above query gives me result set like below

Comment: id     | description  | price   | mulfactor | total  
101    vanilla         10  2     20

Comment: do not use calculation part in query.use multiply whenever need.